# Where HDFS stores data

Tags: hadoop, configuration, hdfs

I am trying to understand where hadoop stores data in HDFS. I refer to the config files viz: `core-site.xml` and `hdfs-site.xml`

The property that I have set is:

- In `core-site.xml`:

  ```
  <property>
      <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
      <value>/hadoop/tmp</value>
  </property>
  ```
- In `hdfs-site.xml`:

  ```
  <property>
      <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
      <value>file:/hadoop/hdfs/namenode</value>
  </property>

  <property>
      <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
      <value>file:/hadoop/hdfs/datanode</value>
  </property>
  ```

With the above arrangement, like `dfs.datanode.data.dir`, the data blocks should be stored in this directory. Is this correct?

I referred to the apache hadoop link, and from that i see this:

- `core-default.xml`:  `hadoop.tmp.dir` --> A base for other temporary directories.
- `hdfs-default.xml` `dfs.datanode.data.dir` --> Determines where on the local filesystem an DFS data node should store its blocks.

  The default value for this property being -> `file://${hadoop.tmp.dir}/dfs/data`

Since I explicitly provided the value for `dfs.datanode.data.dir` (`hdfs-site.xml`), does it mean data would be stored in that location? If so, would dfs/data be added to the directory to `${dfs.datanode.data.dir}`, specifically would it become -> `/hadoop/hdfs/datanode/dfs/data`?

However I didn't see this directory structure getting created.

One observation that I saw in my env:

I saw that after I run some *MapReduce* programs, this directory is created viz:
`/hadoop/tmp/dfs/data` is getting created.

So, not sure if data gets stored in the directory as suggested by the property dfs.datanode.data.dir.

Does anyone have similar experience?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The data for hdfs files will be stored in the directory specified in `dfs.datanode.data.dir`, and the `/dfs/data` suffix that you see in the default value will not be appended.

If you edit `hdfs-site.xml`, you'll have to restart the *DataNode* service for the change to take effect. Also remember that changing the value will eliminate the ability of the *DataNode* service to supply blocks that were stored in the previous location.

Lastly, above you have your values specified with `file:/...` instead of `file://...`.  File URI's do need that extra slash, so that might be causing these values to revert to the defaults.

Comment: Thanks for your response.

When i did the changes like adding extra '/' i am getting exception, at the time of formatting the file system.

    14/03/22 00:18:27 FATAL namenode.NameNode: Exception in namenode join
    at java.io.File.<init>(File.java:423)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NNStorage.getStorageDirectory(NNStorage.java:324)

Please let me know if i am missing something else.

Thanks,
Vipin

Comment: I believe we have to use file:/// and not file://.

Comment: You're right, you need 3 slashes for a file: URI.  Didn't realize that the [format](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1738) has room for a host name. i.e. `file://<host>/<path>` (And the 'host' part is optional, the 3 slashes aren't.)

Comment: The reason i saw /hadoop/tmp/dfs is due to the fact that dfs.namenode.checkpoint.dir  (DFS Secondary name node) uses   file://${hadoop.tmp.dir}/dfs/namesecondary by default, and i didn't change it.

Comment: how would one go about to change the location of this directory, and retain the ability of the DataNode to supply the blocks stored at the original location? I'd imagine just copying the contents of the original folder to the new folder would not suffice, since the hdfs would not now of this change on its index.

Comment: found this to answer my own question: [link] (http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/FAQ#On_an_individual_data_node.2C_how_do_you_balance_the_blocks_on_the_disk.3F)