# How to create hdfs directory for user in Linux at the same time?

Tags: linux, hadoop, hdfs

I can create directory in HDFS under current user directory

```
hdfs dfs -mkdir /user/john.doe/data
```

Above command executed without issue. However `data` directory was not created under `/home/john.doe` directory in Linux

what is the best way to create hdfs directory in associated linux directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you expecting a directory with name `data` under the directory `/home/john.doe`? then the expectation is wrong.

HDFS directories are never materialized to the disk (They are never created on local filesystem). Namenode builds this directory mappings and this datastructure is synced to filesystem periodically.

But files/blocks are materialized to disk. You can see them under the configured location. Read this post for more info.
[Where HDFS stores data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22565200)

Comment: Please close off-topic questions.

Comment: Please don't post answers on obviously off topic/bad questions! [See: **Should one advise on off topic questions?**](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/276572)